# What is the IP address of the SpeakEasy Speed test?

Tags: ip-address

For some weird reasons, I need to unblock the IP address of the speakeasy speed test from my router. I can get to the page, however the actual speed test apparently sends packets to a different IP than the one the website is located on.

It's a web application? So I'm assuming this question goes here, otherwise suggest other forums for the post, and I'll move it there.

I'm looking for the IP address for the Los Angeles based test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used @William's suggestion and used Wireshark to look for the IP address for **Los Angeles**. It showed the IP as **`64.81.45.15`**. I then checked the IP on [ip-lookup.net](http://ip-lookup.net/index.php) and it said the host was `speedtest1.lax1.speakeasy.net`, so it looks like that's the IP you want.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which location you choose for the test.  For example, if you choose Seattle it will be 140.174.11.72.

Comment: Can you get me the Los Angeles one? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you fail in your quest for someone with this info, you can get this yourself using a network packet sniffer.  A good free example is Wireshark.  You can get the hang of the basics of this in about 10 minutes with its help or with online tutorials.  I think you'll find this is a very useful technique to have in your toolkit.

After installing Wireshark, start a capture and access the SpeakEasy page.  Stop the capture, and confirm you see HTTP (TCP destination port 80) packets in the trace.  This is the sanity test.

Then start another packet capture, select the Los Angeles location and start the speed test.  Stop the capture, and near the end you will see attempted connections to the Los Angeles IP.  It helps if you close other applications before doing this, and it's also easy if you can see the live capture while starting the speed test.

Hope this helps!  It's quite likely there is more than one IP in each location, so you might need to repeat this capture to check and unblock more ports.